# Get data from related list w/list of opportunity

Tags: apex, soql, related-list

What I've done is queried the list of opportunities from my developer account and now what I'm trying to do is access the child object of one opportunity. Is there any possible way of doing this without doing any more SOQL queries?

I was thinking that since I have the list of opportunities, I would be able to move down from that parent object and access the child objects. Not sure though

For example, I want to access the competitors of an opportunity and store these results

Answer (score 3):

You can use the inner query to get related list of a Object.

You can verify the Relationship name using [Workbench](http://workbench.developerforce.com) --> Info --> Standard and Custom Object -> Select and Object for which Relationship to be verified

```
    List<Opportunity> oppList = [Select Id,name, (Select Id From OpportunityTeamMembers),  (Select Id From tasks) From Opportunity where Id =: 'some Opp Id'];
    System.debug(':::'+oppList);

    for(Opportunity obj : oppList){
        System.debug(':::'+obj.Tasks);
        for(Task t : obj.Tasks){
            System.debug('Task::'+t.Id);
        }
        System.debug(':::'+obj.OpportunityTeamMembers);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It's also useful to know that the child query ends up as a `List<Task>` (in this case) within each result of the 'parent' object. This inner list of child records can be accessed by `oppList[someIndex].Tasks` or `oppList[someIndex].get('Tasks')`. Also, if your subquery is for a custom object, the relationship name to use in the subquery will contain '__r'

Comment: Also, for those who don't know about the apex workbench: http://workbench.developerforce.com/